# An unhandled exception when using FirstOrDefault() with CollectionViewSource?

Tags: wpf, entity-framework-4, collectionviewsource

I bound entities to a CollectionViewSource. Then I query in code behind. Because the id field is the PK so I think I should use FirstOrDefault() to make my app execute faster. But it always throws an exception ...

XAML :

```
<Window.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="contractlogoesViewSource" d:DesignSource="{d:DesignInstance my:contractlogo, CreateList=True}" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource contractlogoesViewSource}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="grid1" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
...
```

Code behind :

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    VBDAdvertisement.vbdadvertisementEntities vbdadvertisementEntities = new VBDAdvertisement.vbdadvertisementEntities();            
    System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource contractlogoesViewSource = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("contractlogoesViewSource")));
    contractlogoesViewSource.Source = vbdadvertisementEntities.contractlogoes.Where(q => q.id.Equals(3)).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

It throws an An unhandled exception :

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
PresentationFramework.dll
Additional information: 'VBDAdvertisement.customer' is not a valid value for
property 'Source'.
```

But when I omit FirstOrDefault() from the expression tree, like this :

```
contractlogoesViewSource.Source = vbdadvertisementEntities.contractlogoes.Where(q => q.id.Equals(3));
```

It works well !

So why does FirstOrDefault() cause an error ?
Is this case, should I use FirstOrDefault(), will my app execute faster if I use FirstOrDefault() ?

**ps : I am designing an edit form so I just want a single item to be loaded.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you're getting the error is that you can't assign a single item to a CollectionViewSource. If it's an edit form, you probably don't need a CollectionViewSource and could bind to the item directly.

If you do this you can use `FirstorDefault()` to get the first item. But in your case since your selecting by the ID, I think it's better to use `SingleOrDefault()` since it more accurately shows the intention of what you want, like so:

```
contractlogoesViewSource.Source = vbdadvertisementEntities.contractlogoes.SingleOrDefault(q => q.id.Equals(3));
```

`SingleOrDefault()` will throw an exception if more than one item matches the predicate, but since ID is the primary key that's not going to be a problem for you.

If you want to use a CollectionViewSource (but I can't see why), you can use `.Take()` to get a collection containing a single item, like so:

```
vbdadvertisementEntities.contractlogoes.Where(q => q.id.Equals(3)).Take(1);
```

Comment: Hi Ray, the id field is Primary Key so it's also unique. I read somewhere that use FirstOrDefault() will make query faster in case we'are sure there's only 1 record will be returned. In winform, I use FirstOrDefault() with binding source without problem, but wpf doesn't.

Comment: And this is an edit form so that I just need a single item to be loaded.

Comment: @Sun, I updated my answer to make it more clear for you situation.